# Git: unable to connect to server

Tags: git, repository, push

I have a local repo. I have cloned it into a bare repo with

```
git clone --bare myRepo MyRepo.git
```

Then I have copied it in my server with

```
scp -r MyRepo.Git me@myserver:/git/
```

which went well.

I have added a remote to my Repo with (inside MyRepo)

```
git remote add RepoShortcut git://myserver/git/MyRepo.git
```

Now I want to push my local commits to the remote Repo

I've tried

```
git push MyRepo master
```

But git says

> fatal: unable to connect to server:
>   myserver[0: 192.168.1.5]: errno=No such file or directory

Can you imagine what the problem is?

**SOLUTION:**
Seemed I wasn't allowed to write over the git protocol. Solution was to use the SSH protocol..

```
git push ssh://me@myserver/git/MyRepo.git master
```

Answer (score 0):

With `git push MyRepo master` you probably mean `git push RepoShortcut master` (in the context  you've provided)?

I replicated your steps against an empty test repo I created in BitBucket, and everything went fine; the master branch got created in the end using the local bare repo.

Are you behind a proxy by any chance? If so, `https://` URLs might work better for you than `git://` URLs. You can try applying this:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

Comment: So RepoShortcut is actually "MyRepo". So perhaps is that the problem, although git didn't complain about that. So I haven't created a SSL certificate, until now. So https doesn't work until now. Do you think that this is the problem?

Comment: I doubt the name is the problem, it was just not explicit in your example. But the error message you're getting sounds more like a connectivity problem than a Git problem specifically. That's why I think you should try the https URL and see it helps. Also, try cloning a repository (if one exists) from your server so you'll see if downstream works without problems.

Comment: Ok. The solution was to use SSH. I think for some reason I didn't get write rights over the git protocol... Thx